# WebSphere 8.5 Oracle DB: No entries to the CELLONLYDB MSGLOG table

Tags: ibm-bpm

I have installed BAW v18 of WebSphere and deployed a new App on SCA_module.
After i trigger the Interface with SoapUi i would expect to see some logins on DB side in table MSGLog but it is stay empty.
 All data sources were tested successfully.
I can't get why is it empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by given the CELLONLYDB user DB sys rights.